# An $\mathbb F$-algebra as input to an algorithm

Tags: computability, terminology, decision-problem

I want to specify, what it means to give an algebra as input to an algorithm and didn't find very much literature about it. So first I want to ask if you can recommend a book or paper that deals with the topic of complexity analysis of algebras over fields *and clearly define the decision problem*.

After some digging I found *something* and want to share it here and furthermore ask if the definitions make sense and are in compliance with literature (if there is any):

> **Definition:** Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $A$ be a finitely generated commutative $\mathbb F$-algebra with additive basis $b_1,\ldots, b_n\in\mathbb F$. We now want to capture the multiplicative structure of the algebra and therefore write every product of base elements as a linear combination of all base elements:
>   $$
> \forall 1\leq i, j, k\leq n: \exists a_{ijk}: b_ib_j=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ijk}b_k.
> $$
>   The $a_{ijk}$ are called **structure coefficients**. We directly have that:
>   $$ A \cong \left.\mathbb{F}[b_1, \ldots, b_n] \middle/ \left<b_i b_j-\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ijk}b_k\right>_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\right..$$
>   Now one can define the following decision problem:
>   $$
> \{(A,B)\mid A, B \text{ commutative $\mathbb F$-algebras with basis $b_1, \ldots b_n$ and } A\cong B\}.
> $$
>   To specify an isomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ it is sufficient to write every $\phi(b_i)$ as linear combination of the elements of a basis of $B$.

Does anything in this definition seem strange to you or do you think that one can work with it?

> **Motivation:** My motivation behind this is to give a very clear definition of the decision problem first to connect it to other problems, i.e. the problem of deciding polynomial equivalence: Given two polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, we say that $f$ is **equivalent** to $g$ if there exists an invertible linear transformation $\tau$ on the variables such that $f(\tau(x_1), \ldots, \tau(x_n))=g(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. In other words, two polynomials are equivalent if you can replace every variable by a linear combination of all variables to obtain the other polynomial.

I'm not sure if this helps as a motivation but the connection of this problems is established by constructing finitely generated commutative $\mathbb F$-algebras from the two polynomials that are isomorphic if and only if the polynomials are equivalent. For this I wanted to make sure that the decision problem is defined very clearly.

Comment: Does anyone know references besides the one [mhum links to](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2647)?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be consistent with the presentation in [*Equivalence of $\mathbb{F}$-algebras and cubic forms*, Agrawal & Saxena (2006)](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~saxena/papers/stacs06.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Computability over mathematical structure is a long and well established area of research. For example, see:

- Edward R. Griffor, "[Handbook of Computability Theory](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Handbook_of_Computability_Theory.html?id=KqeXZ4pPd5QC)", 1999
- Leonidovich Ershov, "[Handbook of Recursive Mathematics: Recursive Algebra, Analysis and Combinatorics](http://books.google.ca/books?id=rSEFeV98ZIMC)", 1998

or google for:

- computability algebra
- computable model theory